# slf4j simple, is it possible to filter message within the same level?

Tags: java, filter, kotlin, slf4j, log-level

As titled, I just implemented slf4j simple [here](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/assimp) and I got a massive [noise](https://gist.github.com/elect86/e3a74336984f1354f448b9eae72b1bde)..

In that output, for example, I'd like to keep only the `warn`s at the end, that is:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] WARN assimp.Assimp - Collada: No material specified for subgroup <> in geometry <*>.
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Which logging implementation do you use? Because slf4j is just a facade.

Comment: @guenther The question says "slf4j simple", I assume it means slf4j-simple.

Comment: Exactly, slf4j simple

Answer (score 2):

As documented in https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html, you can start with following system properties (if I understood what you want correctly):

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.assimp.Assimp=warn
```

Customize further to taste.